# jquery hasclass for multi tag

Tags: jquery, class

```
<span class="c1 c2"></span>
<span class="c1"></span>
<span class="c1 c2"></span>
<span class="c1 c2"></span>
<span class="c1"></span>
<span class="c1"></span>
<span class="c1 c2"></span>
<span class="c1"></span>
<span class="c1 c2"></span>
```

I have multi span tag and I want test if all tag have c2 class then alert ok .

```
if($('.c1').hasClass('c2'))
{
alert('ok all');
}
else
alert('not all');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an each loop to check if class `c1` has `c2`:

```
$(".c1").each(
    function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("c2")){
            console.log("not all");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u87mW/)

Comment: how i can use this function for alert function?

Comment: Change `console.log` with `alert("not all")` like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u87mW/1/

Comment: but if all span havent c2 alert all run again and again see this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/u87mW/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Check the length instead, as hasClass will return true if any element in the collection has the class

```
if( $('.c1').length === $('.c1.c2').length ) {
    alert('ok all');
} else {
    alert('not all');
}
```

Comment: +1, but if this is in performance-sensitive code (usually things are not), you can cache and filter to avoid re-querying the DOM: `var c1 = $(".c1"); if (c1.length === c1.filter(".c2").length) { ...` (Although with modern browser selection engines, I wonder if that would really be faster...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - The other way to do it would be to filter with jQuery's `not`, something like `$('.c1').not('.c2').length > 0 `, which is probably less performant, but still neat !

Comment: @adeneo: Good point. :-) And the answer is...it depends on the size of the DOM: http://jsperf.com/requery-the-dom-vs-filter The results on that one say cache-and-filter is faster, but when I had fewer elements, it was the other way around. And it varies by browser.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Hmm, interesting. DOM lookup sure has gotten faster when QSA is used internally, in old IE without any proper way to look up classes looking up the elements twice would be horrible I suppose.

Comment: @adeneo: Yeah. Fortunately, unless you're developing for a very specific demographic, you can ignore IE < 8, and IE8+ all have QSA. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yup, and I generally do ignore old IE, and boy has it gotten easier the past few years when you don't have to do all the IE8 nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $("[class$=c2]") will select all elements whose classname ends with 'c2'. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, there are a lot of other variations you can use, for example:

```
[class*=c2] will select elements whose classname contains 'c2'
[class~=c2] will select elements whose classname has the word 'c2' (delimited with spaces)
[class$=c2] will select elements whose classname ends in 'c2'
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way:

```
if ($(".c1:not(.c2)").length == 0) {
    alert("ok all");
}
```